# Add a module dependency to a sandboxed project

Tags: entities

I am developing  custom module which requires the use of the [Entity Construction Kit (ECK)](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) and the [ECK Extend](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mihai_brb/2254845) module. The problem is that the ECK Extend module is a sandboxed module.

I want to add the ECK Extend module as a dependency for my custom module.

How would one do this in the Drupal ecosystem? If I add the sandboxed module as a dependency, will drush recognise it and download it for me when I enable my custom module like drush would normally do with module dependencies?

Comment: Is your question: "How do I add a sandboxed module as a dependendy?" or "How can I get drush to automatically install a sandboxed module I've declared as a dependency?"  Those are very different questions.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that is not possible.

One dirt-fix would be to add the following in your info file.

```
dependencies[] = sandbox/mihai_brb/2254845
```

This will make sure that users will not be able to enable this module by default and cause issues. And then you can add the instructions in your module page and README.txt you can add the instructions about the dependencies and how to download them and then remove the line from the info file.

A better approach would be to use [hook_requirements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7) and in `phase = "install"` you can check for the presence of a function that is present in the sandbox module. If that function is not present, you can block the module installation and show a message to the user to download the sandbox module and then try installing again.